# How to reset score for quizzes independently?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```css
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Resetscr : MonoBehaviour
{
    

    public List<GameInstance> quizInstances;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void awake()
    {
        quizInstances[0].Score = 0;


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

I made a quiz game and I have a score panel, score and game instance. (each test has its own score panel, score and game instance).

I need a button script that on click resets the current test and score panel that will reset the score to 0.

What should I write in my script to make this action happen (score panel and current test transport data of the score from one scene to another and I need the data to be erased just when I click that button).

Should I use a button script for each game instance or is there a way to make it universal?

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using System;
    public class ScorePanel1 : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // better if you can already reference this via Inspector
        [SerializeField] Text text;

        void Awake()
        {
            if (!text) text = GetComponent<Text>();

            // it's always save to remove listeners before adding them
            // makes sure it is added only once
            GameInstance1.OnScoreChanged -= OnScoreChanged;
            GameInstance1.OnScoreChanged += OnScoreChanged;

            // invoke once now with current value
            OnScoreChanged(GameInstance1.Score);
        }

        private void OnDestroy()
        {
            GameInstance1.OnScoreChanged -= OnScoreChanged;
        }

        private void OnScoreChanged(int newValue)
        {
            text.text = "Score: " + newValue;
        }
    }
```

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

    public class Score1 : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Text scoreText;
        public Button button;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start()
        {
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);

            if (!button) button = GetComponent<Button>();
            button.onClick.AddListener(() => { GameInstance1.Score++; });

            GameInstance1.OnScoreChanged -= OnScoreChanged;
            GameInstance1.OnScoreChanged += OnScoreChanged;

            // invoke once now with current value
            Debug.LogFormat("Current Score: {0}", GameInstance1.Score);
            OnScoreChanged(GameInstance1.Score);

        }

        private void OnDestroy()
        {
            GameInstance1.OnScoreChanged -= OnScoreChanged;
        }

        private void OnScoreChanged(int newValue)
        {
            scoreText.text = "Score: " + newValue;
        }


        // These two make not much sense .. since the value already was public
        // you wouldn't need methods for this
        // anyway now you could directly do it on GameInformation instead
        public void AddScore(int s)
        {
            GameInstance1.Score += s;
        }

        public int GetScore()
        {
            return GameInstance1.Score;
        }
    }
```

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using System;

    public static class GameInstance1 
    {
        // Start is called before the first frame update
        private static int _score = 0;



        // have an event to register listeners
        public static event Action<int> OnScoreChanged;

        // public property
        public static int Score
        {
            get { return _score; }
            set
            {
                _score = value;

                // invoke an event to inform all registered listeners
                OnScoreChanged?.Invoke(_score);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you are asking two different questions:

 [What is the proper way to handle data between scenes?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/110958/what-is-the-proper-way-to-handle-data-between-scenes)

How to manage functions for different instances?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide more Details.
Look like some issues with this approach.

```
  button.onClick.AddListener(() => { GameInstance1.Score++; });
```

as there is no Check whether Answer is right or wrong. It will keep adding score.

You can work around your problem by having a single Canvas for entire game and don't destroy the Canvas and gameobject keep the callback of the buttons using

```
 DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
```

Now you need to keep the Refrence of buttons in that script instead of all the Score1 instance, So that Each Score1 instance can add listener and remove listener when required.

Now in Start of each Score1 instance you can do subscribe to the Button Listener and remove old listeners.

```
 private ButtoncallbackHandler buttoncallback;

 void Start ()
 {
  buttoncallback= GameObject.FindObjectOfType<ButtoncallbackHandler >();
  if(buttoncallback)
 {
    buttoncallback.ScoreButton.onClick.AddListener(() => AnswerValidity());
    buttoncallback.ResetButton.onClick.AddListener(() => OnResetClick());
 }
 }

 void AnswerValidity()
 {
  if(answerisCorrect)
  {

   GameInstance1.Score++;

  }
  else
  {
  ///Wrong Answer Logic.
  }

   // Update your Text Box here
   UpdateTextBox();
 }
 void OnResetClick()
 {

  // Do what you want to do in reset
  UpdateTextBox();

 }
```

Similarly Implement the ResetButton, you can do Reset Current Instacne score or all scores depends on you, Keep single textbox for entire game.

Comment: using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using System; what I should add more?